# Error using vertcat by Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am coding with Matlab, and I get the following error for the bold line (**containers = [containers(1:j-1); containers(j+1:end)]**;)

```
Error using vertcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Error in fillContainerWithPolygons (line 77)
                containers = [containers(1:j-1); containers(j+1:end)];
```

The problem is that I get it just sometimes(not always).

Just in case, containers is a set of the matrix, for example I got error for `containers(1:j-1) = [13x2 double] and  containers(j+1:end) =[4x2 double]

I searched and googled a lot but I did not find the problem,
Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, you can avoid that by just saying

```
containers(j, :) = []
```

Also there's something off in your question because `containers(1:j-1)` can't be 13x2, it's got to be nx1. I assume you mean `containers(1:j-1, :)`.

I think the reason is that `j+1:end` is probably just one element, and it's being treated like a column because you're not specifying `j+1:end, :`.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your first part of the answer (containers(j, :) = []). about why containers(1: j-1) can be 13x2, I should say as I mentioned in the question, it is a set of matrix, so suppose j be equal 2, hence we can have containers(1)=[13x2] which is a matrix with 13 rows and 2 columns, and I have to say still I do not know why the previous one was wrong, since j+1:end could be a matrix and it is possible to add it to a set